# How do you speed up a score calculation based on two rows in a Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, performance, optimization

TLDR: How can one adjust the for-loop for a faster execution time:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time

np.random.seed(0)

# Given a DataFrame df and a row_index
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 3, size=(30000, 50)))
target_row_index = 5

start = time.time()

target_row = df.loc[target_row_index]
result = []

# Method 1: Optimize this for-loop
for row in df.iterrows():
    """
    Logic of calculating the variables check and score: 
    if the values for a specific column are 2 for both rows (row/target_row), it should add 1 to the score
    if for one of the rows the value is 1 and for the other 2 for a specific column, it should subtract 1 from the score.
    """
    check = row[1]+target_row  # row[1] takes 30 microseconds per call
    score = np.sum(check == 4) - np.sum(check == 3) # np.sum takes 47 microseconds per call
    result.append(score)

print(time.time()-start)

# Goal: Calculate the list result as efficient as possible

# Method 2: Optimize Apply
def add(a, b):
    check = a + b
    return np.sum(check == 4) - np.sum(check == 3)
    
start = time.time()
q = df.apply(lambda row : add(row, target_row), axis = 1)
print(time.time()-start)
```

So I have a dataframe of size 30'000 and a target row in this dataframe with a given row index. Now I want to compare this row to all the other rows in the dataset by calculating a score. The score is calculated as follows:

1. if the values for a specific column are 2 for both rows, it should add 1 to the score
2. if for one of the rows the value is 1 and for the other 2 for a specific column, it should subtract 1 from the score.

The result is then the list of all the scores we just calculated.

As I need to execute this code quite often I would like to optimize it for performance.
Any help is very much appreciated.

I already read [Optimization when using Pandas](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-the-need-for-optimization-when-using-pandas-8ce23b83330c) are there further resources you can recommend? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to convert your `df` to a `NumPy` array, `NumPy` has some really good vectorisation that helps. My code using `NumPy` is as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 3, size=(30000, 50)))
target_row_index = 5

start_time = time.time()

# Converting stuff to NumPy arrays
target_row = df.loc[target_row_index].to_numpy()
np_arr = df.to_numpy()

# Calculations
np_arr += target_row
check = np.sum(np_arr == 4, axis=1) - np.sum(np_arr == 3, axis=1)
result = list(check)

end_time = time.time()
print(end_time - start_time)
```

Your complete code (on Google Colab for me) outputs a time of `14.875332832336426 s`, while the `NumPy` code above outputs a time of `0.018691539764404297 s`, and of course, the `result` list is the same in both cases.

Note that in general, if your calculations are purely numerical, `NumPy` will virtually always be better than `Pandas` and a `for` loop. `Pandas` really shines through with strings and when you need the column and row names, but for pure numbers, `NumPy` is the way to go due to vectorisation.